# How to animate focus/blur intensity on a VSE strip

Tags: video-sequence-editor

I am trying to animate the focus/blur intensity on a video strip, and have come across  [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qEXAm7HVk98).

It looks interesting, but it's just too fast for me to follow.

I like the fact that it appears to have some parts of the frame in focus and other parts out of focus, and wondered if anyone can spot and explain how this is done.

I assume this script's main purpose is to enable one use the compositor on video strips, right?

Comment: He defines a vertical gradient, which he then uses to control the amount of blur.

Comment: I see, but 1) does he need the script to enable him to do this? 2) I cannot quite see what nodes he is using, so could someone let me know / or provide a blender file?

Comment: Yes, if you want to use the effect in the VSE. If you don't need to do any non-linear editing, you can do it just using the compositor. Here's a .blend: http://www.pasteall.org/blend/31464

Comment: Thanks for that, I can see how to blur the image of the monkey, but I'm not sure how to use the script to enable me to use VSE strips in this way.

Comment: I think the script basically renders an image sequence from the compositor, then imports that into the VSE (I might be completely wrong on this). Anyway, you could do that manually if you don't want to use the script.

Comment: To use any effect from the compositor in the VSE you ADD the composited scene as a strip. The VSE does NOT send media to the compositor.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry the blur implemented in the vse doesn't use an image value for scale (blur quantity is determined by image value), so all you can do is mask the blur strip with a shape (like a texture). Then Alpha it over a copy of the source strip.

Comment: Hi 3point edit, did you post the video in question? I'm relay struggling to follow it. could you please slow it down and upload it at a higher quality, or provide further notes on what you are doing, Thanks.